# Euro symol acting weirdly in a text area of an exported pdf form from OpenOffice-writer

Tags: pdf, openoffice-writer

It somehow seems that the width of the symbol's "collision" is almost 0, but it is rendered as normal.

[image: Here is an example of the weird euros.]

What causes this and is it possible to fix it? I tried searching everywhere but I can't find anything on this bug/feature.
[Example Files of this (.odt and .pdf)](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7rbfw9z6zdi9ngr/AADdsi7gC9v9b5_hQsO9eyWHa?dl=0)

Comment: Inspecting the font information for the text field in the PDF one sees that it claims all glyphs from 127 through 191 have width 0 (**WinAnsiEncoding**, so the € is at 128). As I don't have OOO installed, I cannot dig for the cause of that.